# Can I use event listener and document get Element By Id to change the source of an image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

JAVASCRIPT code is:

```
img1Click = document.querySelector('img#img1')

selected = document.querySelector('section.selected')
img = document.querySelector('img#imgcon')

img1Click.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    console.log('clicked')
   document.getElementById('imgcon').src('images/yellowcake.jpg')
})
```

This code is supposed to make change the src of a img of a div when another image is clicked.

Comment: `.src` is a property that you assign the URL to. It's not a function. (So `.src = 'url'` instead of `.src('url')`.)

Answer (score 1):

You nearly had it, although `src` isn't a function!

You can set it by doing `image.src = ...` or `image.setAttribute('src', '...')`

Here is a simplified example:

```js
const image = document.querySelector("img");

image.addEventListener("click", () => {
  image.setAttribute("src", "https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/200")
})
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200" alt="">
```

Comment: Thanks. I later realized the problem was the src

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can program

```
document.getElementById('id_of_element').src = 'image'
```

Where image is a base64 string or a file path in your directory (x.png).

Comment: You're right. Thank you. I later realized the problem

Answer (score 0):

```js
const imgA = document.querySelector('#imgA');
const imgB = document.querySelector('#imgB');

imgA.addEventListener('click', () => imgB.src = imgA.src);
imgB.addEventListener('click', () => imgA.src = imgB.src);
```

```html
<div>
  <img id='imgA' src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=64"/>
  
  <img id='imgB' src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ugd4YTD60WY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuuclfd8tK4TmHmCGTFZSkqc8VSPTITA/s96-c/photo.jpg?sz=64"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with syntax: `document.getElementById('imgcon').src = "images/yellowcake.jpg"`

```js
img1Click = document.querySelector('img#img1')

selected = document.querySelector('section.selected')
img = document.querySelector('img#imgcon')

img1Click.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    console.log('clicked')
   document.getElementById('imgcon').src = 'https://www.thespruceeats.com/thmb/y9Sj9blj6uM14YUdM6FlZv2dhEI=/2667x2000/smart/filters:no_upscale()/piece-of-yellow-cake-with-vanilla-frosting-186880544-57eade013df78c690fe89768.jpg'
})
```

```css
img {
 width: 400px;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="https://douongcaocap.vn/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/click-here-button.png" >
<img id="imgcon" src="https://www.recipetineats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Chocolate-Cake_9-SQ.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks. I realized too that was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I'm answering my question. I realized I didn't write the correct code syntax. The right syntax is

```
    document.getElementById('imgcon').src = 'images/yellowcake.jpg';
```